# Sync Facebook events from specific page to Google Calendar

Tags: google-calendar-api, facebook-events

Someone must have done this before, I'm trying to sync facebook events from one specific page (so not from my whole account) to a public Google Calendar. I'm assuming I'm going to need the Facebook API for this, but I'm not sure where and how to get started.

Could anyone please push me in the right direction, thanks!